# pd.PeriodIndex is only giving me 12 hours result when I use freq='H'

Tags: python, pandas

I´m using this code to group observations by hour into a dataframe, I first format the date/time column the way I want.

```
timedf.columns = pd.to_datetime(timedf.columns, dayfirst=True, errors='ignore').strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

timedf = timedf.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(timedf.columns, freq='H'), axis=1).sum()
```

Even though I have observations for 24 hours, I'm expecting a (24,1) dataframe, I'm actually getting a (13,1) dataframe, from 0 to 12 hours instead of 0 to 23 hours.

Which could be the cause?

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm I never recall it by heart and I can't find the source for it, but any chance that if you change it to 'h' instead of 'H' that would do the trick? (Sorry I'm not sure, it's jsut the first thing I would try)

Comment: I tried that before and I get the same result